# Run one built-in gradle task before another

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I am running some Android instrumentation tests which require that the app I am testing be a fresh install - the app should not already exist on the phone.

I generally do this by running

```
./gradlew uninstallAll
./gradlew connectedInstrumentTest
```

However, sometimes I forget to uninstall and my tests fail.

**I would like to force `uninstallAll` to run automatically when I run `connectedInstrumentTest`.  How can I do this?**

In my build.gradle, I have tried

```
connectedInstrumentTest.doFirst {
    uninstallAll.execute()
}
```

But this gives me

*Could not find property 'connectedInstrumentTest' on project ':myapp'.*

I tried

```
connectedInstrumentTest.dependsOn(uninstallAll)
```

I get the same error.

This likely comes down to my lack of understanding of Gradle.  I have searched for this but the only examples seem to be around custom tasks, not built-in tasks that already come with Android projects.

Comment: Maybe it will work: `project.tasks.connectedInstrumentTest.dependsOn(uninstallAll)`

Comment: Thanks for replying. I tried that, got an error, but that error led me to a post possibly indicating that I was trying to add this dependency too early.  I've now got something working I will post the answer.

Answer (score 2):

@Opal's comment led me to a bit of reading and I eventually got this working

```
tasks.whenTaskAdded { task ->

    if(task.name.equals("connectedInstrumentTest")){
        task.dependsOn(uninstallAll)
    }
}
```

I *believe* the problem was trying to add the dependency too early, but putting it into `tasks.whenTaskAdded` seems to work just fine. Now when I run `connectedInstrumentTest`, the app is uninstalled first.

Comment: The `android` plugin is special in that it has to defer creation of tasks. Future improvements to Gradle will make this unnecessary.

Answer (score 1):

usually

```
connectedInstrumentTest.dependsOn(uninstallAll)
```

should work, but I think android plugin creates some tasks after the whole buildscript is evaluated. you can try to put the snippet above in an afterEvaluate block:

```
project.afterEvaluate{
    connectedInstrumentTest.dependsOn(uninstallAll)
}
```

cheers,
René